# How to run Node.js on from Google Drive folder

Tags: google-drive

I have a company laptop, a personal laptop and a Raspberry Pi 4.
I tried using GitHub, but it's just overkill so I decided to go with normal Google Drive.
After installing it on Windows (work's machine), it's possible to simply mount it as a drive and open the terminal from there and run nodemon. Said that, I'd like to do something similar on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, but the folder path and contents when I ope the terminal from it are uninteligible, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: There's nothing to fix but there's something to understand: NOT a sync folder. If you want the same functionality you'll have to install a Google Drive sync client as well. Now, the problem is there's no official software for there but there are a few unofficial ones.

Comment: Hi @ChanganAuto! Thanks for your answer. What do you mean "NOT a sync folder"? Everything is there, just the naming convention is extremely off when using the terminal. Nautilus does "translate" everything in a "human" legible scheme.

Comment: I mean it looks like your GDrive content but in order to use any file it must be downloaded.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you! I will try one of the unnoficial versions available in the flathub or snapstore then.